# Calculating the days between two given dates

Tags: python

This coding is to find the days between dates.my coding is not working for  the case which i mentioned as comment at last of code, pls specify my error (note : (y1,m1,d1) -> start date and (y2,m2,d2) -> end date)

```
def days_between_dates(y2,m2,d2,y1,m1,d1):
    days = 0
    tot = 0
    while not(y1==y2 and m1==m2 and d1==d2):
        days = days + 1
        d1 = d1+1
        if((m1 == 4 or m1 == 6 or m1 == 9 or m1 == 11) and d1 == 30):
            d1 = 0
            m1 = m1+1
        if(d1 == 31):
            d1 = 0
            m1 = m1+1
        if (((y1%4)!=0) and m1 == 2 and d1==28):
            d1 = 0
            m1 = m1+1
        else:
            if(m1 == 2 and d1 == 29):
                d1 = 0
                m1 = m1+1
        if(m1>12):
            m1 = 1
            y1 = y1 + 1
        if(y1==y2 and m1==m2 and d1==d2):
            return days
            break
    return days
print days_between_dates(2011,1,1,2010,1,1)
print days_between_dates(2013,1,1,2012,1,1)
#print days_between_dates(2012,2,29,2012,2,28)
```

Comment: Duplicate has been removed from SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Avoid reinventing the wheel, and use the `datetime` module instead:

```
from datetime import date

def days_between_dates(y2, m2, d2, y1, m1, d1):
    return (date(y2, m2, d2) - date(y1, m1, d1)).days
```

As for your error: You are using 0-based date arithmetic; whenever you come to the end of a month, you switch to day 0 of the next month. This means you will **never** hit the end condition if the `y2, m2, d1` day is the last day of the month, for example; before you test for `2012, 2, 29` you already changed the date to `2012, 3, 0`.

Use 1-based arithmetic, and only change the month when you get *beyond* the last day of that month.

Note that you can test equality between tuples, no need to do a full test against each element. Your leap year calculation needs a little refinement too:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    return year % 4 == 0

def days_between_dates(y2, m2, d2, y1, m1, d1):
    days = 0
    isleapyear = is_leap_year(y1)

    while (y1, m1, d1) != (y2, m2, d2):
        days += 1
        d1 += 1

        if (m1 == 2 and d1 == (30 if isleapyear else 29) or
            m1 in (4, 6, 9, 11) and d1 == 31 or d1 == 32):
            d1 = 1
            m1 += 1

        if m1 == 13:
            m1 = 1
            y1 += 1
            isleapyear = is_leap_year(y1)

    return days
```

Comment: A thousand times this.  999 if you're off by one.

Comment: Does Udacity's CS101 grader allow this?  This is exactly the same answer the OP received yesterday and didn't seem to like.

Comment: @user2649815 the mistake is not using the already cre3ated and supplied Python modules

Comment: @Mark: Sometimes, computer classes want you to learn such basics by doing the calculations yourself.